# sonar unit test coverage using cobertura

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to analyze the code and unit test coverage using Sonar, Cobertura and ANT. But somehow it is showing dash ("-") under "Unit Test Coverage" on sonar dashboard. Even it shows "Unit Test Success" as 100%.

I am using following versions:

Sonar: 4.4
Cobertura: 1.6.2
Junit4

Can you please help me to understand the root cause of the issue?

Comment: How and where are you generating a cobertura report ? can you provide the log of the analysis ? Did you configure the report path properly ? Did you follow documentation here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Cobertura+Plugin and there: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project ?

Comment: It is working now. After compiling code in "debug" mode. No idea why we need to compile in "debug" mode.